# Capture COPY & UPDATE command tag from an EXECUTE statement in a PL/pgSQL function?

Tags: plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

When I populate a table from the `psql` terminal:

```
COPY schema.table (
    column_1
    , column_2
    , column_3
)
FROM 'file.csv'
WITH (OPTIONS);
```

the message:

```
COPY x
```

is displayed in the terminal if successful. But when I embed the `COPY` statement in a function e.g. `populate_table` with:

```
EXECUTE format(
    'COPY schema.%I (
        column1
        , column2
        , column3
    )
FROM ''file.txt''
WITH (FORMAT);'
, table_name);
```

and run the function the terminal output is different in that I see:

```
 populate_table 
-----------------------

(1 row)
```

Similarly, if I `UPDATE` with a function I lose the message:

```
UPDATED x x
```

Is it possible to print these messages to the terminal and capture them when working with functions?

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610449/get-the-count-of-rows-from-a-copy-command. The answer points to a new feature of `PL/pgSQL` whereby

> `COPY` executed in a `PL/pgSQL` function now updates the value
>   retrieved by `GET DIAGNOSTICS x = ROW_COUNT`.

Using this information I've tried it as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION populate_table (
    table_name CHARACTER VARYING
)
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
DECLARE    
rows_copied INTEGER;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format(
        'COPY schema.%I (
            column1
            , column2
            , column3 )
        FROM ''file.txt''
        WITH (FORMAT);'
    , table_name);

    GET DIAGNOSTICS rows_copied := ROW_COUNT;
    RETURN rows_copied;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and the terminal message now is:

```
populate_table 
--------------
            x
(1 row)
```

If I further tweak the `psql` settings with:

```
\t [on|off]            show only rows (currently on)
\a                     toggle between unaligned and aligned output mode
```

the terminal output is:

```
x
```

which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, it was your question on SO and the answer to it that helped me out here so this question is really a duplicate. I am not sure what the protocol here is but I am happy to delete this question from here, as it's already been answered over on SO.